# How to Control my Arduino ESP8266 wifi module via my Website( from anywhwre)

Tags: iot, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

for example i made the following page.For controlling two lights(its possible with local wifi network but i want to control my devices from anywhere)
[My Web Page](https://kbiots.000webhostapp.com/)
so how can i access my arduino device from this Globle server.
i need code for ESP8266 to make it this website connected

Answer (score 1):

You are going to control device in real time. so there should be some kind of connectivity needs in between your app and your device. It depends what time latency you are expecting as enough.

HTTP protocol comes with much overheads and latency. Its based on request response model so you will not get that much real time connectivity even you try to request for every 2 seconds then it will become a bad practice and wasting data overheads which is not required in this case.

CoAP is similar model but it works perfect for devices with less memory. as its purpose to make it happen data request from low resource devices like micro-controllers with much possible reduced packet size and headers.

but i think you know mostly people use MQTT protocol to do such things. It is based on publish subscribe model and it is always connected to its broker for further actions in real time.

You may also go for socket programming by your own with which you can connect and listen to your hosted server ( which also has port open and listening for client connections ). in this scenario you need to make set of shake hand rules by your own in between nodes.

I think MQTT is well practised and supported by many communities. you can use publicly available MQTT broker as well. also you will get many mqtt client libraries which you can use to control device remotely in real time

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what approach you want to go with, there are few ways to achieve this:

1. Serve the page from the ESP directly, usually this is the easiest way, since you don't have to care about hosting. The downside of this approach is that the IP you have to access is directly dependent on the ISP.
2. Do the way you started doing it. To successfully implement what you started, you still need to create a server on ESP and receive requests from the front you created. This method has the same problem as the previous one. A hack for this is that you can implement a ping mechanism from your device every N hours as long as you know when the provider will change the IP.

The workaround for the changing IP is using a dynamic IP DNS service. The downside of this is the fact that you will have to setup the router for this to work.

Comment: but i dont have ROUTER,im oprating my all my internet services through mobile hotspot.

Comment: I suspect you might be using some device to create a hotspot, that usually is qualified as router.

Comment: then how to solve the problem of dynamic IP. or how to access 192.168.43.114 from any device Without connecting same hotspot connection to it